# How to get the app account access token needed to administrate app album?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I have a Facebook app, with an associated photo album. Users of the app may upload images to this album, and I have some trouble figuring out how the authentication for this will work in a real life application.

While testing, I've used the Graph API to get a list of my accounts, and copied the access token for the app account into my code. This works, but the access token will expire in a few hours and I have to get a new one and copy into my code.

I tried to automate the process, by going through my user's account in the code, and getting the access token in realtime. This how ever, only worked for me obviously, since other users couldn't access my accounts through the Graph API.

How is this supposed to work in a real life application? That access token is the only one I've managed to upload images with.

Comment: what you mean about associated photo album?! you have a facebook album on a page or user account in facebook & you want let users to upload image in that ?

Comment: That means that the facebook album has been created for, and belongs to the app. Not a user, and not a page.
The album will in other words be returned from Graph through this api call: https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/albums

Comment: This returns Facebook app's old page's album

Answer (score 0):

that must be because other users are not app developer so there is not needed access_token for them,

app pages are removed (but seems photos are available yet) 
if you want to do so i recommend you to open a facebook page for your app Then get page mange permission from your facebook account for the app Then get page access_token & save it (please note that to set your app for 60 days long access_token) Then let users to upload images via page token (this will make users available to upload images as page There is no way to upload an image directly from user account to a page via api yet )